# How to make a Modal Toggle when using Route and Navigation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have four pages, "ReadyScreen" "RunningScreen" "ListScreen" and "CheckScreen"

To start a run, the user navigates from the "ReadyScreen" to the "ListScreen" to the "CheckScreen" and lastly to the "RunningScreen"

ReadyScreen -> ListScreen -> CheckScreen -> RunningScreen

At the end of the user's run, they are navigated back to the "ReadyScreen" from the "RunningScreen"

I want a Modal to toggle with their running info, when the user navigates from the RunningScreen to the ReadyScreen. I have been told I can do this using a route, but I have been having trouble properly setting it up. Here is what I have so far:

```
function RunningScreen({navigation, route}){

const checkFinish = () => {
     onPress: () => navigation.navigate('ReadyScreen, {
     didComeFromRunningScreen: true
 })
}
```

...

```
useFocusEffect(
   React.useCallback(()=>{
   ....
   if(didComeFromRunningScreen){
   toggleModal()
  }
  }, [])
}
```

I am also stuck on how to toggle this in the ReadyScreen

Answer (score 0):

If you are going back to the previous screen you cant pass params like that. or if you forcefully push the previous screen to open again it will create a new stack. You have to pass a callback function from the ready screen to the running screen and in the running screen when your check the finish button press you will call your callback function.

**Here is the code example:**

**ReadyScreen**

```
const ReadyScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const toggleModal = () => {
    // Your modal method to open modal
  };

  // callback func
  const openModalCallBack = () => {
    toggleModal();
  };

  const gotoRunningScreen = () => {
    navigation.navigate("RunningScreen", { openModalCB: openModalCallBack }); // passing callback func
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button onPress={gotoRunningScreen} />
    </View>
  );
};
export default ReadyScreen;
```

**RunningScreen**

```
const RunningScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const checkFinish = () => {
    const { openModalCB } = route?.params;
    openModalCB(); // Here you calling the callback func
    navigation.goBack(); // or pop()
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button onPress={checkFinish} />
    </View>
  );
};
export default RunningScreen;
```

Comment: So in general, I am not allowed to just force navigate back to a screen in any app? To clarify, I have both of these screens existing in a stack navigator.

Comment: Basically, if you use simple navigation.goBack() method then it will just navigate you back to previous screen but in this there is no option for passing params to previous screen. Moreover if you use navigation.navigate("ReadyScreen",{your params}) in your running screen and your readyscreen is already in stack then it will just run as goBack() but not pass the params beacause it is already in the stack. and if you use push() method it will open a ready screen but it will be top on your running screen (not navigate back). Thats why the easy way out is to pass the callback function and call it

Comment: Okay, I am very sorry for the change, but to keep things less cluttered, there are now actually two screens between RunningScreen and ReadyScreen, called: ListScreen and CheckScreen. 

The stackNavigation path now goes: ReadyScreen -> ListScreen -> CheckScreen -> RunningScreen 

The user will still navigate from the RunningScreen to the ReadyScreen at the end of their run; so it is no longer as simple as going back. 

How would this effect your response?